# Foreach return a value many times

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach

I'm trying to work in a PowerShell GUI and got an issue with a foreach prompt.

```
elseif ($ListBox1.SelectedItem -eq 'Specified User Info'){
    [void]$list = $Listbox3.SelectedItem
    $Users = $Textbox.Text

    $DateType1 = Get-ADUser <user> -Properties * |
                 Get-Member -MemberType Properties |
                 where {$_.Definition -like "*int64*"}

    $DateData1 = foreach ($member in $DateType1) {
        $data = $member.Name
        Get-ADUser $Users -Property $data |
            Select @{name=$data;e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_."$data")}} |
            select -Unique $list |
            Out-String
    }

    switch ($listbox3.selecteditem) {
        {$Datetype1.Name -contains $_} {$TextBox1.Text = $DateData1}
        default                        {$TextBox1.Text = $UserInfo}
    }
}
```

As shown in the code, I try get into a variable the properties that are int64 then perform a conversion of there properties into a readable date data.

The issue is that when I get the result in my textbox, for example `PwdLastSet`. the result will show `PwdLastSet` as many time as there's data stored into my variable, and one of these `PwdLastSet` contains the expected result "date and time".

Strangely, this did not occure a few days ago, so it's quite bothering and I'm frankly lost.

I tried to use `ForEach-Object` prompt or different kind of variable in `$DateData1` but the result is still the same. Even `Select -Unique $List` did not fix the issue.

Comment: Does `$Users` contain one user or potentially more than one user? For `Get-ADUser $Users` to yield a result as you have written it, `$Users` needs to have one username. Can you explain what `$list` would contain and why you need something unique based on that?

Comment: '$Users' contains only one user, it recovers the data that will be entered in a textbox.As for '$List', it contain the attribute "property" that is selected in a combobox. [$list] is an example of the way I wrote the command of many, in this case, I tried to encompass my code to make the conversion only on the selected attributes, which in this case did, but still shows a a repetitive list of this said attributes. 
I also used '$data' in the conversion, but in this case, I have all attributes stocked Inside '$data' listed, which is not the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you replace the following:

```
$DateData1 = foreach ($member in $DateType1){$data = $member.name
Get-ADUser $Users -property $data | Select @{name=$data;e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."$data")}} | select -unique $list | out-string}
```

With:

```
$DateData1 = get-aduser $users -property $datetype1.name | select $datetype1.name

foreach ($prop in $DateType1.name) {
$DateData1.$prop = [datetime]::FromFileTime($DateData1.$prop)
}
```

Now, `$DateData1` would contain an ADUser object with all fields converted to the datetime format that you want. You can then manipulate things from there.

To retrieve the contents of `$DateData1` as a string:

```
$DateData1 | Out-String
```

To retrieve the value of a property passed into your switch statement as a datetime type:

```
switch ($item) {
{$Datetype1.name -contains $_}{$TextBox1.text = $DateData1.$_}}
```

To retrieve the value of a property passed into your switch statement as a string:

```
switch ($item) {
{$Datetype1.name -contains $_}{$TextBox1.text = $DateData1.$_.ToString()}}
```

To retrieve the property name and value on the same line, you can use the format operator (`-f`) to format how your output appearance. The output is a string also:

```
switch ($item) {
{$Datetype1.name -contains $_}{$TextBox1.text = "{0}: {1}" -f $_,$DateData1.$_}}
```

Comment: hmm… This works correctly, I actually have the expected results…
Only bummer is that I Don't have the attributes names in the results, if I use this command     
`foreach ($prop in $DateType1.name){$DateData1.$prop = @{n=$DateData1.$prop;e=[datetime]::FromFileTime($DateData.$prop)}`, it shows "System.Collections.Hashtable"

Comment: `$DateData1` has the attribute names as properties. You can see that by typing `$DateData1`. The datetime conversion is already done for you also after my foreach loop code block. It seems as though you just want the display format to be different?

Comment: Yes I see.
And yes, I'm looking to have a complete format in which I have the Attributes name + result

Comment: Well, I fond a way to work arround it, even if it's not the cleanest one, still does the job: `{$Datetype1.name -contains $_}{$ResultBox.Text = $_ + ":" + " " + $Datedata1.$_}` that print the attributes name and the value as expected. 
Thank you very much for the help, I'll be able to work arround with that :)

Comment: Yes. I see what you were trying to do now. That works just fine. An alternative is to use the format operator (`-f`) like so `$ResultBox.Text = "{0}: {1}" -f $_,$Datedata1.$_`.

Answer (score 0):

Additionnally to your answer @AdminOfThings, I found easier way, that seems to work just fine.
Trick was to not use "**Foreach**" at all

```
$DateType1 = Get-ADUser <user> -properties * | Get-Member -membertype properties | where {$_.Definition -like "*int64*"} | select name
$list = $Listbox3.SelectedItem
$Users = $Textbox.Text

$DateData1 = Get-ADUser $Users -property $DateType1.name | Select @{name=$list;e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."$list")}} | out-string

Switch($listbox3.selecteditem){
{$Datetype1.name -contains $_}{$ResultBox.Text = $Datedata1}
```

**$listbox3.selectedItem** is the attributes that will have the conversion
**$Textbox.text** is where the user name is entered

I Don't know why I didn't think of that way earlier, but it seems is does the work as fine as what you gave me, thank you again @AdminOfThings :)

Cheers